# For random variables, $X_1, X_2$, what allows us to write: $P(X_1 = k, X_1+X_2 = N) = P(X_1 = k, X_2 = N-k)$?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

For random variables, $X_1, X_2$, an often used property is:

$$
P(X_1 = k, X_1+X_2 = N) = P(X_1 = k, X_2 = N-k)
$$

This is used most often when $X_1$ is independent of $X_2$, so that we can factor the probabilities apart. However, I am not completely clear why this is the case.

It seems that to get $X_2 = N-k$, we must use information from the entry before the comma, that is $X_1 = k$. I am not quite clear why letting information "slide" across is valid here. Is there another way to see this? Thanks.

Comment: That the events $$\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X_1(\omega) = k, X_1(\omega)+X_2(\omega) = N\}$$ and $$\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X_1(\omega) = k, X_2(\omega) = N-k\}$$ coincide hence their probabilities are equal.

Comment: @Did Is there a way to formally prove this or would it only work to intuitively see it?

Comment: ?? What could be more formal than noticing that one has events $A$ and $B$ such that $A=B$ hence $P(A)=P(B)$? Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no sequential order implied by the "," in a conditional probability.  The comma separates a list of terms in a conjunction.

This is \begin{align*}
    P( (X_1 = k) &\wedge (X_1 + X_2 = N) ) && \text{given/definition}  \\
    P( (X_1 = k) &\wedge (X_2 = N - X_1) ) && \text{algebra}  \\
    P( (X_1 = k) &\wedge (X_2 = N - k) ) && \text{*}  \\
\end{align*}
Where * is a property of equality (the substition property).  If we are working in first order logic, this is a schema: $x = y \iff \forall P, P(x) = P(y)$, where in this example we are using $P(x) = (X_2 = N - x)$

Answer (score 3):

$$
\Big[ X_1 = 13\ \&\ X_1+X_2 = 32\Big] \text{ if and only if } \Big[ X_1 = 13 \ \&\ X_2 = 32-13 \Big].
$$
Therefore
$$
\Pr \Big[ X_1 = 13\ \&\ X_1+X_2 = 32\Big] = \Pr \Big[ X_1 = 13 \ \&\ X_2 = 32-13 \Big].
$$
The probabilities are the same because the two events are the same.